# org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Field 'controller' annotated with @InjectMocks is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

> it's my controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseMessage getUser(@RequestBody AvailableUser uuid) {
                return manager.available(uuid);
    }
```

> it's my testcontroller

```
RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml" })

public class TestController {
    public static final MediaType APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 = new MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getType(),
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getSubtype(), Charset.forName("utf8"));

    public TestController() {

    }

    @Mock
    private static Manager manager;
    @InjectMocks
    private Controller controller;
    private RMessage msg;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }

     @Test 
     public void testgetUser() throws Exception 
     {

         AvailableUser availableUser=new AvailableUser();
         List<String> lst =new ArrayList<String>();
         lst.add("test1");
         lst.add("test2");
         availableUser.setUuId(lst);
         this.mockMvc.perform(post("/user").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(mapper.writeValueAsString(availableUser)))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
         when(manager.available(availableUser)).thenReturn(msg);
     }
    }
```

i got error on the @InjectMocks controller is null.
    it give me hint for that:

> ```
> class SomeTest {
>       @InjectMocks private Foo foo = new Foo();
>
>       @Before public void setUp() {
>          MockitoAnnotations.initMock(this);
> }}
> ```

but i have do that.

> ```
>  @Before
>       public void setup() {
>           MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
>           this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
>       }
> ```

i got error in console:

```
  18:16:20,004 DEBUG CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate:93 - Storing ApplicationContext in cache under key [[MergedContextConfiguration@6483f5ae testClass = TestSurfboardController, locations = '{classpath*:WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
  18:16:20,106 DEBUG DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener:94 - After test method: context [DefaultTestContext@5fcd892a testClass = TestSurfboardController, testInstance = com.verizon.surfboard.TestSurfboardController@8b87145, testMethod = testgetUser@TestSurfboardController, testException = org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Field 'surfboardController' annotated with @InjectMocks is null.
```

> i am properly apply the @InjectMock on the controller after that i
>   have done  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your controller first.

```
@InjectMocks
private Controller controller = new Controller();
```

Neither `@InjectMocks` nor `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup` will not do it for you.
`MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup` is will throw NPE if you are going to pass null value to it.

Comment: ok... when i do that then i got the error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig" on line of "this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();".

Comment: @ShailjaKant Why do you need `@ContextConfiguration` and `@RunWith` if you are mocking your services. I suppose you can just remove these annotations on your test classes.